# To display age in textfield after user has selected date of birth in JDateChooser

Tags: java, listener, jdatechooser

I have a JDateChooser in my program. Whenever the selects his date of birth from JDateChooser , I want his age to be displayed in a JTextField.

Initially, I tried to make it work with the MouseListener as :

```
private void jDateChooser1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{                                                
  Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();  

 //utilDob is a java.util.Date variable which stores date selected by user
 dob.setTime(utilDob);  
 Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();  
 int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
 if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.MONTH))
   age--;  
 else if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                                && today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <    dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) 
     age--;  


 jTextField11.setText(Integer.toString(age));
 displayAge=Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText());
}
```

But, the above mentioned function didn't help me. Is there any other event/action listener I can use?

Comment: You didn't tell us the problem, only that it didn't work. Be sure to include a concise question which sums up what has happened and contrast that with what should have happened.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the code doesn't calculate age. It seems as if the function doesn't execute in the first place.

Comment: So it "seems" like it doesn't execute. You should have debugged before coming here... But anyway, put in a print statement in the function somewhere. Just a good ole normal `System.out.println("Whatever");` in the function, then you'll be able to see if the function is being called if you see "Whatever" pop up in the console.

Comment: It doesn't print the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using outmoded classes.

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the java.time framework built-in.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone. But time zone is critical it determining "today". For any given moment the date may vary around the world by time zone. A few moments after midnight in Paris is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
```

Build a date-of-birth from your user input.

```
LocalDate dob = LocalDate.of ( 1955 , 1 , 2 );
```

Or parse a string compliant with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse( "1955-01-02" );
```

Or use a `DateTimeFormatter` to help parse a different string.

If you have a `java.util.Date` object on hand use a new method added to that old class for conversion to java.time: `java.util.Date::toInstant`. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Apple a time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

### `Period`

Age is just one kind of elapsed time, a span of time. In java.time, the `Period` class represents a span of time tracked in terms of years, months, and days.

```
Period age = Period.between ( dob , today );
```

#### Get years from `Period`

Ask for the years if that is all you want.

```
int years = age.getYears ();
```

Beware that `getYears` is *not* normalized to the full number of years as you may intuit. Depending on how a `Period` is constructed, you may get an unexpected result. Another approach is to call `toTotalMonths()` and divide by 12 (twelve months to a year). See both approaches in this quick example; compare `y` and `y2`.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths ( 25 );
int y = p.getYears ();
long y2 = ( ( p.toTotalMonths () ) / 12 );
System.out.println ( "p: " + p + " | y: " + y + " | y2: " + y2 );
```

> p: P25M | y: 0 | y2: 2

Even better, force the `Period` object to be normalized to a full count of years then months then days. Well, not exactly force the object: Because of [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), you are actually instantiating a new object based on the original object’s values.

So while our `age` object happens to already be normalized because of its particular construction, it might be a good habit to always call `normalized`.

```
Period age = Period.between ( dob , today ).normalized();
```

Dump to console. By default, the `Period::toString` method generates a string according to the [ISO 8601 standard for Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) such as `P61Y2M27D` seen here.

```
System.out.println ( "zoneid: " + zoneId + " | today: " + today + " | dob: " + dob + " | age: " + age + " | years: " + years );
```

> zoneid: America/Montreal | today: 2016-03-29 | dob: 1955-01-02 | age: P61Y2M27D | years: 61

### Convert `int` to `Integer`

Lastly, if you need an object rather than a primitive, convert `int` to `Integer`.

Integer yearsObj = Integer.valueOf ( years );

Comment: Thank u for your response. Well, I have a JDateChooser in my program in which the user will select his/her date of birth and hence I have used java.util.Date. How can I store the date selected from JDatechooser into a LocalDate variable?

Comment: @ninjacoder What object are you getting from that utility? I could not find its JavaDoc nor any guide documentation.

Comment: i am using toedter's JDateChooser